# Extending enums via user input

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, enums

I have the below enum that I use for one of my filters and suit well to my object model

```
public enum ColorGroups
{
    White = 1,
    Brown = 2,
    Red = 3,
    Black = 4
}
```

My concern is in the future when a client want to another color to the collection how do I extend the collection. I want the system to be fully dynamic and does not require a technical person to alter the code for such things..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the data to be user-editable, it may not be suitable to use an enum. Enums are compile-time units, so will require a developer (or some hacky code generation).

Instead, consider using a database table for this data, pre-populated with your items (and perhaps with a "System" column to control which ones are user-defined vs required by the system). Then changes are just inserts (etc) to the table.

You can, of course, use any other storage mechanism - for example, a delimited string in a config file - but I'm guessing you'll want a database somewhere in the system?

Answer (score 1):

An enum may not be the right tool for the job in that case. You would be better off using a set of configuration options. These could be in a config file, in the registry or in a database, depending upon what is available to you and whether you want the configuration to be undertaken by a developer or consultant, or by the users of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the system to be fully dynamic and does not require a technical person to alter the code for such things..

"Fully dynamic" and "use an `enum`" are mutually exclusive if you don't want a technical person to have to get involved to make changes. A database or a configuration file is a better choice here.